# Eclipse is slow, and hangs some times

Tags: eclipse

My workspace has almost of 2 GB, and I am using Eclipse Ganymede with Tomcat 6.0 (as I am working on a dynamic web project).

I am facing a bad development experience as Eclipse is so slow and even hangs on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

I think higher versions are more slow with my workspace.  Please give suggestions on how to remedy this.

Comment: do you placed any breakpoints in your application

Comment: some times it might be the problem

Comment: Having a lot of RAM, a SSD and powerful CPUs certainly help. In case you run Linux, try the tool `atop` which shows current bottlenecks (disk? ram? cpu?).

Comment: 2GB is a one project or a couple? If few just close whose currently not use. The same with plugins, remove if you can remove and you dont need it.

Comment: Ganymede? That's a quite old version. Try to update to a newer version (thinking they will be slower is OK, but you need to try them first). Also close projects you're not using, or try to make separate workspaces.

Comment: i have i5 processor with 4GB RAM, I have tried new versions but found slow. and i have 2 project both are dependent so cant be closed

Answer (score 0):

This may help

In your eclipse,

1) Go to Help

2) Click Eclipse marketplace

3) search - optimizer

install "optimizer for eclipse"
[image]